# Given r blocks of one color and g blocks of another color a tower is made. Show that the max height of the tower is independent of the colors.

Tags: combinatorial-proofs

Given r blocks of one color and g blocks of another color, a tower is formed such that:

- Each level of the tower has width(number of blocks) = width of previous(lower) level -
  1 .
- Each level of the tower has blocks of only 1 type of color.
- Some blocks may remain unused.

My doubt is how to

Show that the **max height of the tower** that can be made **only depends on the total number of blocks and is independent of the number of blocks of each color.**

Original question : https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/478/D (I just have doubt in proof part.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum will be equal to $k$ such that 
$$k = \max_{i \in \mathbb N} \{ \dfrac{i(i + 1)}{2} \leq r + g\}$$

This will give a unique $k$, and tower widths $\{1, 2, \dots, k\}$ top to bottom.
Number levels from top to bottom as $\{ 1, 2, \dots , k \}$

Now consider $r$ (say red) of one colour and $g$ of another colour (say green).

Let's say I increase one colour and decrease another to keep sum the same, i.e. $r - 1$ and $g + 1$.

If the topmost block of width $1$ was red, you can make the original tower again by replacing that with the other colour(green).

Else, if it was green, then since there must exist levels $i$ and $i -1$ ($i \geq 2$)
 such that $i$ is made of red and $i - 1$ by green, you can swap the colours of those two levels (of widths $w$ and $w + 1$ where $w \geq 1$) so that from the original tower now you have the same height but colours $r - 1$ and $g + 1$.

Without loss of generality, this also works for $r + 1 $ and $g - 1$. So you can keep increasing one colour and decreasing the other till you get any required combination of colours. This also proves that it is, in fact, possible to make such a tower in the first place.

I may have missed some boundary case, which you can easily provide proof for.

Comment: Thanks , I got it now.